# ARM Assembly - what does it mean to add something to the SP(stack pointer)?

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse-engineering, cracking

Basically I'm trying to counter a dlyb hack that gives some advantage to hackers on my game. In it there's an injectHack function that does this in the beginning:

```
//This is the function: injectHack(char*, int, char*, int)
push {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr} //Pushes args in reverse order + the link register
add r7, sp, #0xc //What is it doing here? Adding r7(the first char*) to the stack pointer? And what is #0xc?
```

There are also some lines where it stores some fixed addresses like this:

```
ldr r0, [r0]
str r0, [r7, #0xffffffbc]
ldr r0, [r0]
```

I don't get it, it's loading from `r0` to `r0` twice for no reason? Could this address be the function they're going to hook?

Comment: `add r7, sp, #0xc` adds the current value of the stack pointer and the immediate value 0xc (12 in decimal notation), and stores the result in `r7`.

Comment: Also, `r4-r7` do not contain the function arguments; `r0-r3` do. The reason for pushing `r4-r7` is because functions must preserve the values of those registers.

Comment: so it increases by 12 the top value of the stack? Isn't the last pushed thing the link register? So the function returns to a different point?

Comment: No, `add r7, sp, #0xc` doesn't alter anything on the stack, nor does it alter the stack pointer itself. It takes the value of the stack pointer (i.e. the address of the current stack top), adds the value 12 to it and places the result in a different register (`r7`).

Comment: Note that `r7` is typically used as the [frame pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_pointer#FRAME-POINTER) in Thumb code (and most compilers will emit Thumb code by default for CPUs that support it).

Comment: The 2nd portion is like `struct node { struct node *next; ...}` with the 'C' code `struct node *n = root; local = n; n = n->next;`.  Ie, the `ldr r0, [r0]` is traversing some pointer list/structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arm architectural reference manuals do a pretty good job of explaining things in pseudo code.

Yes, effectively the registers are pushed in reverse numerical order, the largest number register (r14) is pushed first then r7 and so on.

the arm calling convention uses r0-r3 for parameters and with maybe one exception you cant mess with the other registers without preserving them so r4-r7 in this case are being preserved as well as lr, this function is likely calling another function.  Note an odd number of registers is being pushed so this is an older calling convention, the current one always keeps the stack pointer 64 bit aligned.

the add r7 is not modifying sp, it is just making a pointer into the stack.  the fourth word in 0x00 (r4) 0x04 (r5) 0x08 (r6) 0x0C (r7)

So they are making a pointer to whatever value was in r7, very strange but perhaps whatever it is you are looking for.

note the load of r0 from the address r0, modifies r0, pointer = *pointer; then that address is preserved at the address in r7 - 0x44 whatever that points to.  they they go another level of indirection with the pointer in r0,  pointer = *pointer.

That is about all you have provided us with, but if you would get an arm architectural reference manual from infocenter.arm.com you could just look up the instructions and read the pseudo code. to completely understand every instruction.

The *ARM Architecture Procedure Call Standard* (AAPCS) is described in the appropriately named ["Procedure Call Standard for the ARM Architecture"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf) document. There's another document describing the procedure call standard for 64-bit ARM architectures (AAPCS64).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why #0xc is used, usually I see #0 being used.

In Thumb mode, r7 is used as the frame pointer (look at the disassembly on page 2 [here](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Eprabal/teaching/eecs373-f10/homework/homework1/solution1.pdf) as an example). When you enter a function, you push to the stack the registers you will use, so as to be able to restore them when you return. `push {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}` does this, and then usually do a `add r7, sp, #0` to save the current stack pointer into r7, so that when you are done doing stuff in the function, you can set sp = r7 and that will put you in a position to simply `pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}` out of the stack into the registers, and then `bx lr` to return.

Not sure if the 0xc is related to the hack?